# ASP.NET MVC multi-instance session management on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, session, multiple-instances, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application written in asp.net mvc2. Currently hosted on amazon cloud ec2.
Because of growing traffic we want move multi instance enviorenment. I have a custom session class which currently initiate at session start (global asax) and i am using via getter or setter class in application. Because of multi instance chore i have to handle hole security architecture. I am looking a better way to handle this problem.

I am looking for good implementation of session and how to apply on amazon ec2 multi instance environment. What is road blocks for system architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have our web app running on EC2, but its a basic ASP.NET App, not MVC. We got around the session state issue by pointing both of our servers to to a SQL box, which they where going to talk to anyway, and used that for Session State. Another option is to use something like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Membase](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/membase-server) as your session state, and share the state across multiple machines that way.

The only obstacle i can think of is around naming of machines. Each instance will change when they reboot, so what you would need to do is something as follows:

- setup a master memcache or membase server. this should set a DNS record for itself on boot.
- on machine start, get the current instance ip address, and register it with either memcached or membase (membase i think is easier for this).
- on shut down, disconnect from the master server.

there is a [Memcached Session State and Cache Provider on CodePlex](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/) which should easily help you do what you need to do.

Again, the way we got around it was SQL server... This was easier for us to setup, but i am not ruling out a memcache/membase option any time soon either...